# Data stored in directories based on date. How to get all data from date1 until date2?

Tags: python, directory, dataset

I have a python app that will be storing a large amount of data as custom python objects through jsonpicke.

Currently my project has a data file with this structure:

```
....
data/
    year/
     ...
        month/
        ...
            day/
            ...
                A/
                    data_file_1
                    ...
                    data_file_n
                B/
                    data_file_1
                    ...
                    data_file_n
```

here I was just representing multiple potential dirs or files as '...'

I would like my user to be able to specify a start date and an end date from which I will parse all the data.

Currently my data set is quite small, and so moving it around is no problem. Furthermore the data doesn't need to be human readable, so whatever format doesn't really matter at this stage.

Is there an easier way to store this data so that I can get the data whenever I need, update it when necessary. Another library, package or just better directory layout?

If not, than my question is a bit more specific.

My solution so far has been:

```py
import os

...

def get_data(path, dates, data):
    """
    @param path: str representing
    the current path being searched.

    @param dates: list of tuple 
    representing (min, max) dates
    to be considered

    @param data: empty list, used
    for collecting the data of the
    files.
    """
    if len(dates) <= 0:
        #This case occurs when the subdirectories
        # under the current path don't have any constraints.
        # as such I can grab all the files without worry.

        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for file in filenames:
                data.append(dirpath + '/' + file)

    else:
        min, max = dates[0]
        dirpath, dirs, files = os.walk(path).next()

        for dir in dirs:
            value = int(dir)

            if value > min and value < max:
                #unconstrained case
                get_data(path + '/' + dir, [], data)

            elif value == min:
                #TODO recurse with boundary case minimum
            elif value == max:
                #TODO recurse with boundary case maximum
```

However these boundary cases have stumped me. If I am given some abritrarily determined dates. Lets say:

```
# from 8/21/2011 -> until 12/7/2014
dates = [(2011, 2014), (8, 12), (1, 7)]
```

The problem is then how should I set up the date to be passed into the recursive method in the boundary cases?

Am I missing a simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime` objects to represent the dates, increment with day deltas.

Pseudocode:

```
import os.path
import datetime
def f(t0, t1):
    t = t0
    while t != t1:
        day_path = os.path.join(t.year, t.month, t.day)
        if os.path.exists(day_path):
            # Do what you need inside the day dir.
        t += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```